# Relative motion/velocity vector problem: What bearing should the pilot take...?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

I spent a few hours on this problem and seem to be getting nowhere.
The question is:

> A plane flies at speed 252 km/hr in still air.  Today there is a wind blowing at speed 72.8 km/hr at 58.4o east of north.  If the pilot wishes to fly due north with the wind blowing, find φ, the angle between the direction the pilot aims the plane (west of north) and due north.

I think I got an angle of 14*WN. But my answer was wrong.
Does this problem require the use of Law of Sines/Cosines? or am I overdoing/overthinking?
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hello and thanks. I read the Meta post you referenced. It is kinda confusing TBH. This is not HW. But in any case. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have misinterpreted what is meant by the statement

> Today there is a wind blowing at speed 72.8 km/hr at 58.4o east of
>   north.

Is that the direction from which the wind is blowing or the direction in which the wind is blowing?

You are given the speed of the plane relative to the air $v_{pa}$ and the velocity of the air (wind) relative to the ground $\vec v_{ag}$ and the required direction of the plane relative to the ground $\hat v_{pg}$.
Construct a vector triangle to solve the problem.

$$v_{pg} = v_{pa} + v_{ag}$$